Postman, force request to Wordpress PHP plugin endpoint
As a beginner, I'm currently developing my third WordPress PHP plugin with an endpoint, using Postman for GET test requests.
Interestingly, I've noticed that if a request is identical to the previous one (because I only changed something in the endpoint, for instance), the request appears as if it was never made, and the response is instantly the same as the previous one. However, if I update a parameter with a new value, the next request is made as expected.
Currently, the endpoint simply returns a random number. But again, if I don't change the parameter in the request, the response contains the same number as the previous one, even though it should have changed. Could this be due to a misunderstanding on my part about how Postman and/or WordPress work?
This situation is preventing me from visualizing the changes I make in the plugin until I change a parameter in Postman, which is quite frustrating. I apologize in advance if this question seems naive.

Sounds like you have just discovered caching for the very first time :-) We can't tell from what minimal info you provided so far, if your code does anything specifically to instruct the client on caching behavior. In general, GET requests usually get cached "easier", with POST requests that is rather seldom the case. [...]

[...] So either switch to using POST (if you need this for any AJAX background requests or something), or include a cache buster with your GET requests. (That is basically what you already did, by changing URL parameters. A general cache buster usually simply appends the current timestamp, or a random value.)

Alright! Then cache it is! Happy to discover this, I understand better how to force it ... Thanks!
